# calling .net core method from angular gives error: failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am very new to both angular and .net core. I am writing a sample project,
 In this project, I am calling a method from angular to .net core. I keep 
 getting an error saying:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()     api/AllItProjectsLists/index:1
```

I have a breakpoints on angular side  on method getProjectDetails(). nothing happens when I click on 
 F11 on this line

```
return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Index').pipe(map(
```

Below is my full angular side code:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AllItProject } from '../../models/allitproject';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectDetailService {

  myAppUrl = '';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
  }
  getProjectDetails() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Index').pipe(map(
      response => {
        return response;
      }));
  }
```

In my .net controller, I have defined AllItProjectsLists :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProjectDetails.Models;
using ProjectDetails.Data;
using ProjectDetails.Interfaces;
namespace ProjectDetails.Controllers
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KPIContext _context;
        private readonly IProject objProject;

        public AllItProjectsListsController(IProject _objProject)
        {
            objProject = _objProject;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/AllItProjectsLists/Index")]
        public IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList> Index()
        {
            return objProject.GetAllProjectDetails();
        }
    }
```

this is what I have in my .net startup.cs file

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<KPIContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        services.AddCors();
    }
```

I keep getting loading... on my web browser

Error from the console window:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponseerror: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/AllItProjectsLists/Index</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"headers: HttpHeaderslazyInit: () => {…}arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: ""__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: http.js:120[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {}__proto__: Objectmessage: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index: 404 OK"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 404statusText: "OK"url: "https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6014
handleError @ core.js:6066
next @ core.js:40557
schedulerFn @ core.js:35335
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:185
```

I changed the code, the way you told me and I am getting status code 500 error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponseerror: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www"headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index: 500 OK"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 500statusText: "OK"url: "https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6014
handleError @ core.js:6066
next @ core.js:40557
schedulerFn @ core.js:35335
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:185
```

Below is my changed code:

This is how I changed my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProjectDetails.Models;
using ProjectDetails.Data;
using ProjectDetails.Interfaces;
namespace ProjectDetails.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KPIContext _context;
        private readonly IProject objProject;

        public AllItProjectsListsController(IProject _objProject)
        {
            objProject = _objProject;

        }


        [HttpGet("Index")]
        public IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList> Index()
        {
            return objProject.GetAllProjectDetails();
        }

  }
```

My entire startup code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ProjectDetails.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace ProjectDetails
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<KPIContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
            services.AddCors();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My entire error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
core.js:6014 
RROR HttpErrorResponseerror: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www"headers: HttpHeaderslazyInit: () => {…}arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: ""__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: http.js:120[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0)size: (...)__proto__: Mapclear: ƒ clear()constructor: ƒ Map()delete: ƒ delete()entries: ƒ entries()forEach: ƒ forEach()get: ƒ ()has: ƒ has()keys: ƒ keys()set: ƒ ()size: (...)values: ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Map"get size: ƒ size()__proto__: Object[[Entries]]: Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Objectappend: ƒ append(name, value)applyUpdate: applyUpdate(update) {         /** @type {?} */         const key = update.name.toLowerCase();         switch (update.op) {             case 'a':             case 's':                 /** @type {?} */                 let value = (/** @type {?} */ (update.value));                 if (typeof value === 'string') {                     value = [value];                 }                 if (value.length === 0) {                     return;                 }                 this.maybeSetNormalizedName(update.name, key);                 /** @type {?} */                 const base = (update.op === 'a' ? this.headers.get(key) : undefined) || [];                 base.push(...value);                 this.headers.set(key, base);                 break;             case 'd':                 /** @type {?} */                 const toDelete = (/** @type {?} */ (update.value));                 if (!toDelete) {                     this.headers.delete(key);                     this.normalizedNames.delete(key);                 }                 else {                     /** @type {?} */                     let existing = this.headers.get(key);                     if (!existing) {                         return;                     }                     existing = existing.filter((/**                      * @param {?} value                      * @return {?}                      */                     value => {…}clone: ƒ clone(update)constructor: class HttpHeaderscopyFrom: copyFrom(other) {         other.init();         Array.from(other.headers.keys()).forEach((/**          * @param {?} key          * @return {?}          */         key => {…}delete: ƒ delete(name, value)forEach: forEach(fn) {         this.init();         Array.from(this.normalizedNames.keys())             .forEach((/**          * @param {?} key          * @return {?}          */         key => {…}get: ƒ get(name)getAll: ƒ getAll(name)has: ƒ has(name)init: init() {         if (!!this.lazyInit) {             if (this.lazyInit instanceof HttpHeaders) {                 this.copyFrom(this.lazyInit);             }             else {                 this.lazyInit();             }             this.lazyInit = null;             if (!!this.lazyUpdate) {                 this.lazyUpdate.forEach((/**                  * @param {?} update                  * @return {?}                  */                 update => {…}keys: ƒ keys()maybeSetNormalizedName: ƒ maybeSetNormalizedName(name, lcName)set: ƒ set(name, value)__proto__: Objectmessage: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index: 500 OK"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 500statusText: "OK"url: "https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Open network tools (F12 in the browser). What is the API that gets submitted?

Comment: It is going to my controller. Above error that I posted is by F12 tools. The error says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()     api/AllItProjectsLists/index:1                        Index is the method in the controller. I did specified the route on the Index method. My above post specifies that

Comment: Let me try again... In F12 tools, hover over the the red line in the Name column and write what is the URL of the API (it should start with http or https). Also, while you are there - what is the error in the console window. It starts with GET or POST.

Comment: I put the error from the console window in my original post. I hovered over the name columns and the URL is: https://localhost:44313/api/allItprojectslists/Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly KPIContext _context;
    private readonly IProject objProject;

    public AllItProjectsListsController(IProject _objProject)
    {
        objProject = _objProject;

    }

    [HttpGet("Index")]
    public IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList> Index()
    {
        return objProject.GetAllProjectDetails();
    }
}
```

or

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly KPIContext _context;
    private readonly IProject objProject;

    public AllItProjectsListsController(IProject _objProject)
    {
        objProject = _objProject;

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList> Index()
    {
        return objProject.GetAllProjectDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code, the way you told me and I am getting status code 500 error. I pasted the error above in my original question. I also put the changed code right after the error.

Comment: I added my full startup and the error at the bottom of my post. Sorry for the late reply, my computer was having some issues.

Comment: You need to get the exception from the server-side error log. Without that it's all shot in the dark!